# Variable-coefficient Laplacian identity proof

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis, tensor-products, vector-fields, laplacian

Does the following hold?

*μ* Δ***u*** + [(∇***u***)^T] ∇*μ* = ∇ · (*μ* ∇***u***)

Where:
*μ* is a scalar function,
***u*** is a vector function,
^T is the transpose operation.

In other words: is variable-coefficient Laplacian combined of const-coefficient Laplacian and product of the transposed vector gradient and coefficient gradient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the product rule to expand the RHS in either *index notation*
$$\eqalign{
\def\BR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\LR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\a{\mu}\def\b{{\bf v}}\def\n{\nabla}\def\p{\partial}
\p_k\LR{\a\:\p_k\b_j} &= \LR{\p_k\a}\LR{\p_k\b_j} + \a\LR{\p_k\p_k\b_j} \\
}$$
or *vector notation*
$$\eqalign{
\p\cdot\LR{\a\n\b} &= \LR{\n\a}\cdot\LR{\n\b} + \a\LR{\n\cdot\n\b} \\
}$$
verifies the relationship.